# Non-empty intersection with the interior of a convex set

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

Let $C$ be a convex set in the plane with non-empty interior, and let $x \in C$ be a point on its bourdary.

Prove that, for each open neighborhood $N$ of $x$ there exists $y \in N$ which belongs to the interior of $C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take three distinct non-collinear points in the interior [with closed convex hull $N$]. Then the interior of the cone from $x$ to this convex hull is made is contained in the interior of $C$ and has non-empty intersection with $N$.

Answer (score 0):

A connected component of the boundary of a set in the plane is simply given either by points or a curve.

Suppose there exists $x \in \partial C,$ and a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $N \cap \text{int} (C) = \emptyset.$ Then, for all $y \in C,$ the line $L_{xy}$ joining $x$ to $y$ is in $C$. $L_{xy} \subset C$ for all $y \in C$. But, there exist a set of lines $\mathcal{L}$ such that for all $y \in C$, $N \cap L_{xy} \in \mathcal{L},$ otherwise $N$ has to contain some element of the interior of $C$. But moreover, for each line $L$ in our family, and for all points in $z \in N \cap L,$ for all neighborhood $z \in \mathcal{U}$ is not included in $\mathcal{C}$. By translating your neigborhood along your line, you see that it is true for any point on your line away from $x$. This implies that $C$ as empty interior, which is a contradiction.